# Ansible conditional task processing

Tags: ansible

I need some help on an ansible playbook. Using this sample playbook, I would like to modify this playbook in such a way that if the hostname of webservers1 equals "123.456.000", do not bother running the remaining parts of the playbook.

```
- name: test play 1
  hosts: webservers1
  serial: 2
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: first task
      command: hostname

- name: test play 2
  hosts: webservers2
  serial: 2
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: first task
      command: hostname
    - name: second task
      command: hostname

- name: test play 3
  hosts: webservers3
  serial: 2
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: first task
      command: hostname
    - name: second task
      command: hostname

- name: test play 4
  hosts: webservers4
  serial: 2
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: first task
      command: hostname
    - name: second task
      command: hostname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**If the hostname of webservers1 equals "123.456.000", do not bother running the remaining parts of the playbook.**"*

A: It's not possible to break a playbook from a play, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - meta: end_play

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Start play 2
```

the playbook proceeds to the second play

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Start play 2
```

---

There is still an option to test a variable at the beginning of each play. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[webservers1]
srv1 ansible_host=123.456.000
srv2 ansible_host=123.456.001

[webservers2]
srv3 ansible_host=123.456.002
srv4 ansible_host=123.456.003
```

The playbook below tests the condition in the first play and sets the variable. The next plays test this variable, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        _break: "{{ '123.456.000' in groups.webservers1|
                    map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host')|
                    list }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: webservers1
  tasks:
    - meta: end_play
      when: _break|bool
    - debug:
        msg: Start webservers1

- hosts: webservers2
  tasks:
    - meta: end_play
      when: _break|bool
    - debug:
        msg: Start webservers2
```

should break the next two plays

```yaml
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************
ok: [srv1]

PLAY [webservers1] ************************************************************

PLAY [webservers2] ************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
srv1: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```